# Antonym of "smalltalk"?

Tags: antonyms

[According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Small_talk&oldid=606623266), smalltalk is an informal type of discourse that does not cover any functional topics of conversation or any transactions that need to be addressed. For example:

- William: Morning, Paul.
- Paul: Oh, morning, William, how are you?
- William: Fine, thanks. Have a good weekend?
- Paul: Yes, thanks. Catch you later.
- William: OK, see you.

I haven't found a word to describe the opposite: an informal type of discourse that DOES cover a functional topic of conversation or a transaction that need to be addressed.

Could we say "deep talk"? Maybe just "non-smalltalk" is the best option?

Comment: deep conversation

Comment: Curiously, people who don't like to get deeply involved in ***small** talk* often have ***heavy** conversations*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should have made this an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure of the meaning of "heavy conversation" @FumbleFingers: I just asked for the meaning here: [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167553/what-does-heavy-conversation-exactly-mean](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167553/what-does-heavy-conversation-exactly-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer to the conversation I have with closer friends which is the opposite of small talk as

```
Deep/Meaningful/Insightful talk
```

Comment: I think all answers are correct. Personally, I like more both this one and substantial talk (from @Elian) because I can say: "I like insignhtful talks" or "I like substantial talks". If I say "I like serious conversations" or "I like discussions" or "I like conversation" or "I like to talk", it sounds less clear for me.

Answer (score 4):

I would call it **serious conversation**.

Answer (score 1):

I would say either discussion or discourse, or even intercourse, although intercourse doesn't necessarily imply that the talk actually achieved a communication objective.

Answer (score 1):

"talk" would be the best option.

If you say to someone "We need to have a talk" or "Can we have a talk?", it obviously implies a meaningful one.

Consider also [**meaty**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meaty) and "**substantial**" talk (or *discussion*, *conversation*).

Answer (score 1):

> substantive
> suhb-stuh n-tiv/
> adjective
>
> having practical importance, value, or effect.

A substantive conversation as opposed to "small talk"

> small talk
> smôl ˌtôk/
> noun
>
> polite conversation about unimportant or uncontroversial matters, especially as engaged in on social occasions.

Both a substantive conversation and small talk are also in contrast to a rhetorical argument.

> rhetorical
> rəˈtôrək(ə)l/
> adjective
>
> expressed in terms intended to persuade or impress.

To best choose which term to use, consider the content, intention and setting.

Comment: Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here.

Comment: @NVZ happy to provide additional information. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I would say conversation would be the most appropriate antonym. Smalltalk is a subset of conversation. The characteristics of this subset dictate that it has no functional topic. Once you remove this charateristic, it just becomes conversation.

Answer (score 0):

What about having a one on one or a heart to heart/heartful convo, can I speak to you in private?,  I always liked the "No, but seriously...." Line but meaningful is another good one.  I'm just trying to think of something short and simple.

> **heart to heart**
> a serious conversation between two people, usually close friends, in which they talk honestly about their feelings
> [- Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heart-to-heart)
>
> A heart-to-heart is a frank and honest conversation with someone, where you talk honestly and plainly about issues, no matter how painful.
> [- usingenglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/heart-to-heart.html)

Comment: Hello and welcome. I like your suggestion of "heart to heart". It can be helpful to cite and link to definitions and usage examples in order to support your answer. I've added a couple for you. Feel free to add more, edit these, or roll them back.

Answer (score 0):

**brass tacks**, as in the idiomatic phrase ["get down to brass tacks"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_down_to_brass_tacks).

Answer (score 0):

Although less common, the term **big** or **large talk** certainly does exist, as attested by the users in [this Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-there-small-talk-and-not-big-talk).